# Saving file to drupal site using drupalgap

Tags: 7

I am trying to save an image from Android emulator to a Drupal site using [DrupalGap](https://drupal.org/project/drupalgap), but I am unable to do this.  This is my ajax call which I wrote to save the data to drupal site.

My click function

```
   $('#page_node_create_submit').on('click',function(){

try {
      var title = $('#page_node_title').val();
      if (!title) { alert('Please enter a title.'); return false; }

      var body = $('#page_node_body').val();
      if (!body) { alert('Please enter a body.'); return false; }

      var filef = $('#page_node_filef').val();
      if (!filef) { alert('Please select file.'); return false; }

     //var datastring = 'node[type]=drupalgap&node[title]=' + encodeURIComponent(title) + '&node[language]=und&node[body][und][0][value]=' + encodeURIComponent(body) + '&node[files][field_filef_und_0]=' + '&fid=47' + '&uid=1';
     //alert(datastring);
     //return false;

      $.ajax({
          url:"http://192.168.1.146/drunew/?q=services/session/token",
          type:"get",
          dataType:"text",
          error:function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(errorThrown);
          },
          success: function (token) {
          // BEGIN: drupal services node create login (warning: don't use https if you don't have ssl setup)
          $.ajax({
              url: "http://192.168.1.146/drunew/?q=my_services/node.json",
              type: 'post',
              data: 'node[type]=drupalgap&node[title]=' + encodeURIComponent(title) + '&node[language]=und&node[body][und][0][value]=' + encodeURIComponent(body) + '&node[files][field_filef_und_0]=' + encodeURIComponent(filef),
              dataType: 'json',
              beforeSend: function (request) {
                        request.setRequestHeader("X-CSRF-Token", token);
                     },
              error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert('page_node_create_submit - failed to login');
                console.log(JSON.stringify(XMLHttpRequest));
                console.log(JSON.stringify(textStatus));
                console.log(JSON.stringify(errorThrown));
              },
              success: function (data) {

               $.mobile.changePage("main.html", "slideup");
              }
          });
          // END: drupal services node create
          }
        });
    }catch (error) { alert("page_dashboard - " + error); }
return false;

});
```

But the above code is not working for file field, then after doing some R&D I got to know that first we have to get the fid, then save it.

Below is the respone after creating the fid for the image.

```
{"fid":"47","uri":"http://192.168.1.146/drunew/my_services/file/47"}
```

Here my doubt is how can I integrate this response in my above ajax call to save the image in drupal site.

Any help, thanks..

Answer (score 1):

Once you have the File ID, that means you've successfully saved the file to your Drupal site. Next up (typically), you'll want to attach that File ID to a new/existing Entity (e.g. node).

If you are creating a new node, use a POST, if updating an existing one, use a PUT.

**New**

> /my_endpoint/node.json

```
{
  type: 'article',
  language: 'und',
  title: 'Hello',
  file_images: {
    und: [ {fid: 12 }]
  }
```

}

**Existing**

> /my_endpoint/node/456.json

```
{
  type: 'article',
  language: 'und',
  title: 'Hello Again',
  file_images: {
    und: [ {fid: 12 }]
  }
```

}

FYI, the latest version of DrupalGap now supports image fields, so you shouldn't have to write any custom code.